# duktape startup duk_create_heap_default panic exit

Tags: interpreter, duktape

I tried to compile Duktape with IAR compiler for STM32F4 micro.
I have build a first minimal sample program but ends in panic

```
#include "duktape.h"
int main()
{
  duk_context *ctx = duk_create_heap_default();
  duk_eval_string(ctx, "print('Hello world!');");
  duk_destroy_heap(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

The last four call stack procedure are

```
duk_err_longjump  
duk_throw
duk_js_compile
duk_do_compile
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the same test but giving the following options in the compiler command line:

```
-DDUK_OPT_DEBUG -DDUK_OPT_DPRINT -DDUK_OPT_ASSERTIONS -DDUK_OPT_SELF_TESTS
```

Self test or assertion errors might give a clue what's going wrong.